# jquery mobile - event not working after form submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm attempting my first jquery mobile site, which will be converted into an app (also first time). There's a button that when clicked displays all results via `AJAX`. However, if a form has been submitted on any "page" and you return to click it again, nothing happens. The form submits successfully (the search doesn't work yet, but add recipe does), as all the data is being entered into the database as expected. There's no errors in the console either. Any idea as to why this would happen?

I found a similar question, but no answer was given. So I'm hoping for one here.

It can be viewed here:
http://jessemorgan.me/recipe/

Thank you

Comment: What is meant by "nothing happens"? What are you expecting to happen?  Right after you say nothing happens you then say the form submits successfully so it isn't quite clear what you're asking for.

Comment: The jquery event that's suppose to happen when the "View All" is clicked. After a form is submitted, it no longer works and no errors are thrown.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In your JQuery method it sounds like your AJAX modifies the HTML on the page in order to show the results.  Is this done via an append or replace of the HTML? Your bug is often due to the newly displayed HTML being malformed or causing the page to have malformed HTML and your button is rendered invalid. You won't see log errors because the button click is not being seen by the browser. Check the source in your browser with something like Chrome and it usually highlights HTML errors in red. Do you see any errors in the HTML?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I checked it in Chrome and didn't see anything highlighted. I'm using `.append` to add it to this: `<dl data-role="listview" data-filter="true" id="output"></dl>` by its `id` and the times when it doesn't work, it's just like that. Empty opening and closing `dl` tags. After a form is submitted, it refreshes the page. Could that be why for some reason?

Comment: Sorry, try firefox for viewing the source. Yes, the refresh could be a part of the problem because the HTML is fine on initial load, but breaks when new (possibly malformed) HTML is added and then loaded on refresh. For example, if your "View All" button falls after the <dl> and you append code that is missing some closing tag somewhere, then your button may show on the page, but it won't be responsive. If you see red code in Firefox, hovering over it will give a brief reason for the problem. This is the most common problem in my code but we both know there are other possible explanations.

Comment: No red code, however I did just get it to work. I changed the `method` from `get` to `post` and did not make the form submit. So it runs my query now, but the data comes out all screwy for some reason. Initial problem solved though. Thank you for getting me to think on it more.